# MVC 5 Identity Automatic Logout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin, asp.net-authentication

How do I implement an Automatic Logout Timer.

So basically if the user is inactive for x minutes their session is ended?

I have tried:

```
<system.web> 
   <sessionState timeout="1"/>
</system.web>
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Here is code that is in my startup:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
  // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
   });
 }
```

Which says that I am using cookie Authentication. So i dono what that entails if I can do it or not.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Its a property in the `App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs` file:

```
  app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
      ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
      AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
      LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
   });
```

Comment: May I ask where do you find information on this? I.e where is it documented? What are all the settings options I have available?

Comment: Also is it possible to make the system redirect or show a page saying timed out please login again?

Comment: Sure if you have an [Authorize] attribute protecting your action it automatically redirects you to the LoginPath in the options there.  Aka it redirects you to the login page.

Comment: What I meant is like with internet banking, It must popup saying that your session has expired and you have been automatically logged out. Please login again. I want that to be displayed as the users session is timed out.

Comment: @Zapnologica - It would be fairly trivial to write this yourself using window.setTimeout in the front end. The main issue you would have is with multiple tabs, so rather than *show* the warning after the timeout - you'd want to make an Ajax request to the server to verify if the user was still logged on, and show your popup/layover based on that response. If you require more detail, please ask a new question.

Comment: I believe the correct name is ExpireTimeSpan. Might have changed in the update to V2.

Comment: Could you say how do we have configure web.config in that case? Thank you!

Comment: Hi Kung. I follow your approach but it doesn't work for me. I set ExpireTimeSpan and added [Authorize] but still is user logged wht time expire.

Comment: ExpireTimeSpan is used to dictate how long a "Remember Me" cookie will remember the logged in user, through closing the browser, etc.

Comment: i have used this property, but it seems to be not working, any idea why?

Comment: This doesn't work. `ExpireTimeSpan ` is used when you want to expire the user session even if the user is still active.  For inactivity first you need to set the `SlidingExpiration` to  true and then add the following code. `Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnResponseSignIn = context =>
                    {
                        context.Properties.AllowRefresh = true;
                        context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10);
                    }
                }`