# MVC 5 Auto Log Off user with OWIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

I review some posts about that but I can't still find answer on my question.
I trying to create auto log off for users who spent more then defined time. Example if I specified 30 min web app need to automatically log off user.

I am using OWIN with MVC 5 and my configuration in Startup.Auth class are:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                                       {
                                           AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                                           LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                                           CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.SameAsRequest,
                                           SlidingExpiration = true,
                                           ExpireTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, expireMinutes, 0, 0),
                                       });
```

and also:

```
app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());




        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
            new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Wreply = WAADReturnURL,
                Wtrealm = realm,
                MetadataAddress = metadata,

            });

        app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            new Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = "xxxx",
                ClientSecret = "xxxx", 


            });


        app.UseYahooAuthentication(
            new YahooAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ConsumerKey = "xxxx",
                ConsumerSecret = "xxxx", 
            });


        app.UseLinkedInAuthentication(
            new LinkedInAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                ClientId = "xxxx",
                ClientSecret = "xxxx", 
            });

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "xxxx",
            ClientSecret = "xxxx", 
        }); 

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = "xxxx",
            AppSecret = "xxxx",
        });
```

I am using WAAD and third party providers such as Facebook, Linkedin...

Also my web.config I set following configuration:

```
<authentication mode="None">
</authentication>
```

I review following post also but without solution:
[MVC 5 Identity Automatic Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21604019/mvc-5-identity-automatic-logout)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in your `Startup.Auth.cs` class set `SlidingExpiration` to `false`. If set to `true`, Identity auto creates a new Application Cookie in second half of specified TimeSpan and user is automatically signed in.